# Creating a Windows Phone 8 GUI using C++

Tags: c#, c++, api, import, windows-phone-8

I have been handed an API written in C++ to create a `Windows 8 phone app`. As I understand it I can import this API into a c# project?

> If so, how would I go about doing that?

The image below shows the basic example project on the Win 8 web site. I have simply dragged the `NetQCheck.h` and `NQC`.....lib files into the project. Can I use a simple `#import` to make use of the API?

[image]

Comment: Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: So I won't be able to use the imported c++ API with an XAML GUI as stated on your link above? Can you point me to a page explaining how to create a GUI in a pure C++ project?

Comment: As far as I've understood it should be possible, although I've never tried it. From the above link: `Windows Phone 8 supports Visual C++ 2012. This is the full version of C++ that is available on the desktop, and the two versions use the same compiler and IDE. This means that your phone app can reuse existing C and C++ libraries that you have developed for other platforms, in addition to third-party libraries and middleware.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import c++ libraries into a Windows PHone 8 app, you need to create a Windows Runtime Component. 
Open your app in Visual Studio. Right click the solution and select Add->new project
Select Windows Runtime Component.

For more steps, see this [MSDN help file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_CreatingandConsumingWindowsRuntimeComponents).